# python pypdf2 pdfreader pdfwriter close file after write

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to open the file using pypdf2 pdfreader and pdfwriter and finally close the file after processing it. As I want to move that file to another folder.

Following is my code

```py
import sys
import os
import shutil

from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

pdf_path = "12-1805-0001842092-00.pdf"
reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)
writer = PdfWriter()
for i in range(0, len(reader.pages) - 1, 2):
    lhs = reader.pages[i]
    rhs = reader.pages[i + 1]
    lhs.mergeTranslatedPage(rhs, float(lhs.mediabox.right), 0, True)
    writer.add_page(lhs)
    sys.stdout.flush()

with open(pdf_path, "wb") as fp:
    fl = writer.write(fp)

fp.close()

if os.path.exists("1805") == False:
    os.mkdir("1805")
shutil.move(pdf_path, "prodcode\\" + pdf_path)
```

I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/pyGUI/main.py", line 30, in maxim
    maximus()
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\pyGUI\maximus.py", line 601, in maximus
    genfpgpdf()
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\pyGUI\maximus.py", line 475, in genfpgpdf
    os.remove(pdf_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: '12-1805-0001842092-00.pdf'
```

Comment: Is it possible that the file is open with an other program?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is the minimal code. This reads each page from pdf file and merges every two pages into one page. e.g. if the pdf contains 12 pages the resulting pdf will have 6 pages